# Can't run interactive hashcat inside a while read loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to run hashcat in a bash script multiple times in a loop. The issue that I'm having it that, because hashcat is interactive, the script executes it multiple times over. I would like to run the first hashcat command and, only when that finishes, the second one should run.

Script example:

```
while read dict
do
    hashcat -m 0 -a 0 hashfile.hash $dict
done < dictionary_paths
```

Also, what about nested while loop?

For example:

```
while read rule_right
do
    while read rule_left
    do
        hashcat -m 0 -a 1 hashfile.hash dict.lst dict.lst --rule-right=$rule_right --rule-left=$rule_left
    done < $rule_left_file
done < $rule_right_file
```

Comment: Proib better for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: what version of hashcat are you using - and where is it coming from (e.g. Ubuntu packages, Gentoo portage, etc ...)

Comment: @IwanAucamp, with my bash hat on, this behavior would happen with *any* tool that reads from stdin, not just hashcat, so the version isn't particularly relevant.

Comment: BTW -- in general, passing `$dict` unquoted is usually a bad idea (likely to result in... lots of unexpected behaviors; for instance, a `*` will become a list of files in the current directory, a string `"foo bar"` will be split into one word `"foo` and another word `bar"`, etc). Is each line one argument? Multiple arguments? If the latter, separated how?

Comment: (As another aside, storing filenames in a newline-delimited list isn't always a great idea, because *filenames can themselves contain newlines*. Assume someone does something like `mkdir -p hello$'\n'/etc/passwd` -- if you then ran `printf '%s\n' ** > hashfile.hash` with the `globstar` shell option enabled, you'd then have `/etc/passwd` as a line in your file. The safer format for a file containing a list of files is NUL-delimited).

Comment: tsk tsk, re: editing a question in a way that invalidates existing answers. But that said, I'll edit my answer appropriately here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry and thank you! (New here and very grateful for all the help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate answer here is to use a file descriptor other than stdin:

```
while IFS= read -r dict <&3; do
    hashcat -m 0 -a 0 hashfile.hash "$dict" # assuming dict is just one argument
done 3< dictionary_paths
```

The `3<` means we open `dictionary_paths` on FD 3, and then the `read ... <&3` redirects FD 3 to stdin during the read operation itself. Consequently, FD 0 -- stdin -- remains directed to its original source (such as a terminal) during the script's operation.

---

For a nested loop, use a different FD at each level:

```
while IFS= read -r rule_right <&3; do
    while IFS= read -r rule_left <&4; do
        hashcat -m 0 -a 1 hashfile.hash dict.lst dict.lst \
                --rule-right="$rule_right" --rule-left="$rule_left"
    done 4<"$rule_left_file"
done 3<"$rule_right_file"
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you! Is there any way to do this with nested while loops as well?  I'm also using this with left-rule and right-rule, nested.

Comment: Use a different file descriptor at each nesting level -- so, say, `3` for the first, `4` for the second.

Comment: ...that said, you might want to consider reading the inner list into an array (as with `readarray -t` if you're on bash 4.x) so you don't need to reread the file once per outer-loop iteration, assuming it isn't too large to fit in memory conveniently.

Comment: I **think** I understand. Just updated the question to be more clear. Regarding arrays, I'd be worried that it'd be heavy on memory - would love to hear your thoughts. What about reusing IFS in the nested loop?

Comment: Yes, using an array would definitely cost you some memory. Whether that cost is worth it depends on the size of your `rule_left_file` and how much memory you *have* -- and whether this is CPU, IO or memory-bound to start with.

Comment: When I run `IFS= read`, that's scoping the change to IFS to the `read` command -- it doesn't affect any other command -- which is why it needs to be run again later. You *could* move the `IFS=` to its own command, but then you'd need to either reset it later or be aware of the consequences in the rest of your script.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are awesome. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: Clicking the "this answers my question" checkbox would suffice. :)