# Read response in bash loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm going to write script in bash, I want read output from another application, and ask user for action.

```
psql -c "SELECT userid, name  FROM my_table"|
while read userid name
do 
    do_something  $userid $name
done
```

Inside of function do_something i want ask "are you sure etc". But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Replace `do_something` with simple `echo` and show what happens

Comment: It works, very good
'1001 Mike
1004 Marco
1003 Tom'
in function do_something i want to ask user are you sure etc. 'read -p "Are you sure (y/n)? " answer '

Comment: I am assuming that the edit I did was a fix for typo (you had forgotten to add `read`)

Answer (score 1):

> read output from another application

### `ls -1 | while read i; do echo "$i" ; done`

`ls -1`, like output
`|` re-direct output
`read` , get output and put in `i`
`"$i"`, now you can print it

---

Now, inside your `while` you can do anything, like invoke a function or something else

---

read:
`read --help`

---

as script:

```
for i in $(ls -1)
do
    echo -n "Are you sure (y/n)?" && read ans
    if  [ $ans == "y" ];then
        echo $i
    fi

done
```

Comment: please try to run this 'ls -1 | while read i; do echo "$i" ; read -p "Are you sure (y/n)? " answer;  done' I do not see questions

Comment: @mario you can write between `do` and `done` an `if` to do that

Comment: I do not understand. It doesn't confirm action before deletion. <br>
ls -1 | while read i; do echo "$i" ; read -p "Are you sure (y/n)? " answer; if [ "$answer" == "y" ];then echo "I'm deleting"; fi;  done

Comment: On another note, @k-five, code segment like `for i in $(ls -1)` is [HIGHLY discouraged.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @anishsane  thanks, but this was a simple sample and I want that `mario` to understand, However I do not use it again :)

Answer (score 0):

This should probably help: (Logic copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38357303/793796))

```
while read userid name <&3
do 
    do_something  $userid $name
done 3< <(psql -c "SELECT userid, name  FROM my_table")
```

Explanation:
When you are running `command | while read` loop, the `stdin` of entire while loop is being redirected from the process output. So, any `read -p "Continue? [y/n]" response` that runs inside the while loop would also have the redirected `stdin`. You want it to be from terminal.

Solution: redirect `stdin` of only the `read` command on the `while read` line. This code above creates an additional file descriptor #3, redirected from `psql` command's output.

`<(command)` is the standard syntax for [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution).